# Using cccc with pure C?

Tags: c, static-code-analysis

Has anyone used [cccc](http://cccc.sourceforge.net/) with pure C code?

I tried it and it seems to handle all the files as one module, which means that most of the counters are useless (e.g. there is no fan-in or fan-out since there is just one module).

Can I somehow tell it to do this comparison on a file-by-file basis (i.e. each file is one module)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems a little bit outdated. I usually use [sloccount](http://www.dwheeler.com/sloccount/) with good results.

Comment: I'd like to get other metrics besides line count, such as cyclomatic complexity.